# Can Bottle's rebase() and include() be made to run from templates in memory?

Tags: python, template-engine, bottle

I can get *rebase()* and *include()* to work with templates files on disk using `rebase("base_template.tpl")`, but am not seeing how to get this to run with templates stored in memory.

Here is my current effort:

```
from bottle import template

base_template = '''\
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{title or 'No title'}}</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{!base}}
</body>
</html>
'''

inner_template = '''\
% rebase(base_template, title='Page Title')
<p>Page Content ...</p>
'''

print(template(inner_template, base_template=base_template))
```

The above code results in a *TemplateError*.

Comment: FWIW, I found [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/) to be just as simple as Bottle's built-in templates, but more robust and better thought out. Possible workaround for you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a known issue with bottle, and this discussion  https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/521 mentions a workaround.

However, no clues if it's working or not with latest version.